# Standard visitor or fiance visa

Tags: united-kingdom

I am an Indonesian citizen and my boyfriend is a British citizen. We got to know each other through an online forum, discovered we have many common interests and ultimately led to his first visit to Indonesia in the middle of 2017.

Now we are planning for me to visit him next March for about 3 to 4 months and after that I will go back to Indonesia with him (we plan to get married in Indonesia).

We both work with enough income and have no financial issue to settle down.

1. What options are available for my situation regarding visas?
2. If I apply for a standard visitor visa, I understand that I have to convince the ECO that will be back to my country once my proposed visit is done. However, to stay in the UK for a few months, I will have to quit my job. Will the ECO assume I do not have strong ties to my country?
3. If I apply for a fiance visa, does it require us to get married in the UK only? For some reasons, we actually plan to get married in Indonesia and will apply for a UK spouse visa after that.

I have never been to the UK, this will be my first visit and I do not wish to ruin it.

Comment: Quitting your job as part of applying for a visitor visa is definitely a bad idea. Any chance your company would allow a longer period of leave?

Comment: Employee in Indonesia is entitled to receive 12 days of annual leave per year. My company implements the same.
I have talked to my superior and unfortunately, I got no chance of having longer period of leave.

Comment: If you apply for a fiance visa, yes you are expected to be married within that 6 months in the UK. As you've described your plan, there is not set of visas that cover this scenario. If you quit your job, you will almost certainly not be granted a standard visa from Indonesia. There is no such thing as a boyfriend/girlfriend visa.